# How to duplicate the legend of one subplot into another subplot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using Matplotlib to plot some simple figure. An exmaple is illustrated like follows:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 5, 1000)
fig =plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
ax  =plt.subplot(211)
ax.plot(x, np.sin(x), '-b', label='Sine')
ax.axis('equal')
leg1 = ax.legend(loc= (0.8,0.85));
leg2 = ax.legend(loc= (0.8,-0.15));
leg2.set_zorder(14)
ax.add_artist(leg1)
ax.add_artist(leg2)
ax  =plt.subplot(212)
```

I want to keep the upper and lower subplot both have the same legend as the subplot 1.

[image]

However, when I turn down the `leg2` in order to within the second subplot, it is covered by the canvas. Here is my question, Is there any method to duplicate the legend of one subplot to another subplot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the second legend is part of the first subplot, and the first subplot is completely behind the second.

Ususally, you would add the legend to the second subplot instead of the first.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 1000)
fig =plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
ax  =plt.subplot(211)
ax.plot(x, np.sin(x), '-b', label='Sine')

leg1 = ax.legend(loc= (0.8,0.85))

ax2  =plt.subplot(212)
leg2 = ax2.legend(*ax.get_legend_handles_labels(), loc= (0.8,0.85))


plt.show()
```